# Issue with my count variable

Tags: python

I keep getting an error for the line which contains" count = 0". I'm not sure why because that is original default value I'm trying to set..

```
max = int(input("enter The number of butterflies that is required: "))
count = 0

while count <= max:
    butterfly=int(input("how many butterflys did u see: "))

    if butterfly >=1:
        count = butterfly+count
    else:
        count=count

    butterfly=input("how many did u see: ")

print("you have reached,",max)
```

ERROR LINE: 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 5
    if butterfly >=1:

Comment: You should post the error line, plus you're missing a trailing bracket

Comment: `count = count` is completely superfluous.

Comment: Also try to avoid using the variable name `count` or `max`... or any other Python functions, methods, or keywords.

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 5
    if butterfly >=1:

Comment: If you use an appropriate editor or IDE, they will help you with spotting such errors.  Happens all the time.  Note also that the error is actually in the line above, because the interpreter thinks your count statement belongs to the previous function call.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close parenthesis on line 1 and have an extra one in line 14

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example

```
max = int(input("enter The number of butterflies that is required: "))
count = 0

while count <= max:
    butterfly=int(input("how many butterflys did u see: "))

    if butterfly >=1:
        count += butterfly

    butterfly=input("how many did u see: ")

print("you have reached,",max)
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but now its giving me:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 5
    if butterfly >=1: